# Mean covariate value in msm

Tags: r, markov-process

I've been going through the manual of the R `msm` package for multi-state Markov models and have a question regarding how the default intensities are reported. The code below is taken from the documentation:

```
twoway4.q <- rbind(
  c(0, 0.25, 0, 0.25),
  c(0.166, 0, 0.166, 0.166),
  c(0, 0.25, 0, 0.25),
  c(0, 0, 0, 0)
)

cavsex.msm <- msm::msm( state ~ years, subject=PTNUM, data = msm::cav, qmatrix = twoway4.q, death = 4, 
  covariates = ~ sex)
```

Now, I've defined

```
intens1 <- msm::qmatrix.msm(cavsex.msm)
intens2 <- msm::qmatrix.msm(cavsex.msm, covariates = list(sex = mean(msm::cav$sex)))
```

The default value of the `covariates` parameter of the `msm::qmatrix.msm` function is 'mean'. Indeed, `msm::qmatrix.msm(cavsex.msm, covariates = 'mean')` gives the same response as `intens1`; 'mean' here is defined as 'denoting the means of the covariates in the data'.

The question: why are `intens1` and `intens2` different? The latter pre-calculates the mean of the sex covariate and passes it to the function, but I would think the responses should be the same.